# Using JavaScript and a separate React component, is there a way for me to switch to a Bootstrap tab pane with an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm creating an application where I have a generic schedule view which contains a sidebar with Bootstrap nav tabs to switch between a month/calendar component and a week/timeslots component. I want to make it so that when I click on a day of the month on the calendar component, it will switch back to the timeslots component (where it will dynamically adjust to the selected day of the month). Is there a simple way for me to make it so that an on click event on a day has the same effect on the tab content as clicking on the nav tab that switches to the tab pane with the timeslots component?

HTML:

```
<div className="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div className="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-timeslots" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-timeslots-tab"><Timeslots /></div>
                        <div className="tab-pane fade" id="nav-calendar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-calendar-tab"><Calendar /></div>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
<div ... onClick={(e) => {
                    const el = e.target.closest("div");
                    if (el && e.currentTarget.contains(el)) {
                        actions.setTimeslotsStartingDay(...)
                    }
# want to show nav-timeslots tab-pane here
}
>
                </div>
```

Sorry if these code blocks end up formatted weird, this is my first time using StackOverflow.

The first result on Google recommended something like this:

JS:

```
$('[data-target=#nav-timeslots]').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

I tried using this exact code pretty much, and I was hoping this would switch tab panes to the timeslots tab, but it didn't work.
Looking at this code a little closer, it's pretty clear why it didn't work, and it's not really what I'm trying to do. But what would work?